# Nest framework with typeorm and mysql the Column default property is modifying the database values to default value on every server reloading

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I created a TypeORM entity `@Column({default: 'I tied with a lot of type and more  value'})` what returns to original value ( what is in default 'I tried... ) on every server reload or code modification with watcher.

```
@Column({default: 'I tied with a lot of type and more  value'})
is_active: string;
```

Answer (score 3):

I removed the dist directory after it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would need a bit more clarification to really understand what is happening, but it sounds like you may have `synchronize: true` in your TypeORM config. This will make TypeORM re-run all of its set up functions (table creations, column modifications, etc.) on server startup.

Comment: I tried to update my packeges in pacgage.json to last version of packages.
https://github.com/ladape/ANIstack

Comment: I can see in you ormconfig.exmaple.js file that synchronize is set to true, but can you give a bit more detail about what is going on? What file I should be looking at in your Git repo?

Comment: Column default is working with the "old" Column, such as a role in  user.entity.ts. The role is working perfectly just the newly created Columns are not. Why? WTF?

Comment: my ormconfig.js is same as the ormconfig.example.js now, thanks for the review :) <3 I think it was a change of indispensable thing to run in production mode.

Comment: So user.role is working as expected. Can you tell me which entity is having the problem? There's a lot of entity files to look through for one issue.

Comment: It just tried to add to user.entity.ts  the isActive property.

Comment: Okay, I think I finally see, in `mysql` Booleans are mapped to type `TINYINT` but TypeORM handles this conversion for you, so you should be able to use `@Column({default: false})` instead of `@Column({default: 0})` and TypeORM will correctly convert the column value for you.  [This github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/642) goes into greater detail about it.

Comment: I tried modify in the database manually the default value for example: @Column({default:  'any string here'}) myproperty: string;  to 'my modified value' and it roles back to default 'any string here' string on server reload ( code modification with watcher ) Not just the boolean works like this. I don't know why. Do you have an idea for this?

Comment: As I answered above, you have `synchronize: true` set in your `ormconfig.js` file. What synchronize does is it will run any administration and set up work according to your decorators. This means if you have `@Column({default: 'someString'})` set and you manually go to your database `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DEFAULT someOtherString` and then restart your server, TypeORM will rewrite the default of `COLUMN` to `someString` as your decorators say to do so. Check out the [documentation here](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/)